# Door Access system - list checking

Tags: python

first post here on stack overflow :D
Firstly, at school currently i'm working on a little door entry system and most of the code (only short maybe 30 lines max) is at the school pc - however ive just downloaded Anaconda because i cant get python to download and im using Spyder,
And im trying to sort out a little error im getting so i can fix it at school, pretty much i want to allow the user to enter a code that will be stored into the 'code' variable and then if the 'code' is in the 'database' variable the door will open if not it'll tell you access is denied and loop the program for the next person/next attempt - What i have here to post is the bare minimum of my program but its pretty much the part im struggling with - i have had the program working multiple times with the codes being presented seperately but im looking on making them into a list instead for easier usability - and its a challenge thats been set

```
while True:
    code = input ('Please enter your user ID ')
    database = ['001','002','003']
if code == database:
    print ('access granted')
else:
    print ('Acess denied')
```

Thats my code so far :D

Comment: How could a list be equal to a string? Do you mean `if code  in database`? Also you should probably create the list outside the loop and make it a set

Comment: New to coding and python so sorry for all the questions which are probably a little bit silly, what do you mean make it a set?

Comment: You should consider using raw_input over input. input will evaluate the raw input, e.g. "001" -> 1

Comment: @FrederikH,  nope not in python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `in` not `==`:

```
database = ['001','002','003']  # create once
while True:
    code = input('Please enter your user ID ')  
    if code in database:
        print ('access granted')
        break # break if code is in our list
    print ('Access denied') # or print access denied and ask again
```

You are currently comparing a list to a string as in `if "001" == ['001','002','003']` etc.., `in` tests for [*membership*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm) as in is this element contained in my list.

On another note for small datasets it is irrelevant but when doing a lookup over larger sized datasets using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) is a very [efficient](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) way to test for membership:

```
 database = {'001','002','003'} # set literal
```

If you don't want to break an are not validating forget the while and just ask the user once:

```
def get_access(db):
    code = input('Please enter your user ID ')  
    if code in db:
        print('access granted')
        return True
    print('Access denied') # or print access denied and ask again
    return False
```

Then to use the function:

```
database = {'001','002','003'}
granted = get_access(db)
if granted:
   .............
```

If you do want to loop indefinitely you need the else:

```
    while True:
        code = input('Please enter your user ID '):
        if code in db:
            print('access granted')
        else:
            print('Access denied')
```

Comment: im getting an invalid syntax error on the line 5 - i expect maybe a indention error? ill play around with it a bit

Comment: @JoeRodgers, yes,  fixed

Comment: Hmm, weird now im getting a syntax error on line 4 D:

Comment: missing paren, having issues with copy/pasting.

Comment: nevermind, i managed to delete the closing bracket on line 3, however it isnt looping

Comment: It loops if the wrong code is input, but if the correct code is input the program finishes

Comment: @JoeRodgers,  yes, that is generally what you want, you break and move on when you get valid input. Do you want to continually ask the user for the same valid input?

Comment: Yes, so that when hypothetically John (Who has the code 001 assigned to him) enters the building the door entry system resets so Mary (Who has the code 002 assigned to her) can later enter the building too

Comment: @JoeRodgers, you would use it as a function, every time you get a new user run the function

Comment: when i removed the break to try it out it responded by both granting and denying access

Comment: @PadraicCunninghamHow would i do that?

Comment: @JoeRodgers, yes because there is no else, I removed it as it is superfluous with the break there

Comment: So basically this validates users by checking if their code is in the db?

Comment: database = ['001','002','003']
while True:
    code = input('Please enter your user ID ')
    if code in database:
        print ('access granted')
    else:
        print ('Access denied')

Comment: Sorry i tried posting my new code as it works for me just to share but i dont know how to format it

Comment: @JoeRodgers, that is an infinite loop, putting the logic in a function and doing it per user will be a lot more maintainable

Comment: Yeah i'd like for the code to be in an infinite loop so many people throughout the day can open the doors to access / leave the building

Comment: So the script is going to run infinitely?

Comment: I really like your code :D , i have a few questions so could you maybe move this too a chat? i dont have enough rep yet

Comment: Then you need the else, I cannot move us to chat either as your rep is too low!

Comment: Yeah ive got the else, how do i post my code without it compacting - My question has been answered but now im more curious about making it more efficient and how to use functions too!

Comment: The only way to change the complexity is to use  a set as your database  `O(1)` vs `O(n)` lookups , to make it a function just do what I did with the second part to my answer but remember while loops block so that is all that is going to be happening in your code

Comment: Have you maybe got skype then so i can chat with you over the code?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply knocked out my ethernet cable :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95790/discussion-between-joe-rodgers-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:-

```
database = ('001', '002', '003')

while input('Please enter your user ID ') not in database:
    print ('Acess denied')

print ('access granted')
```

As the other answer said you need to be testing if the input is in (or not in) the database list.